# Fundamental solution for a parabolic PDE with costant coefficents

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

as it is well known, the fundamental solution of the heat equation is the function

$G(t,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}$,

for all $t>0,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I wonder if exists (and if you have same references) a similar explicit formula for the fundamental solution for a parabolic PDE with constant coefficents.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by a parabolic PDE? If you can make a linear change of coordinates so that you end up with the heat equation, you can write the fundamental solution in terms of the one for the heat equation and the change of coordinates.

Comment: It is alway possible this strategy of change of variables?  I mean $\partial_t-L$ where $L$ is a second order elliptic operator with constant coefficent. Later I am interested also in parabolic operators with higher order.

Comment: It is not really that straightforward, but the fundamental solution should not be too different from the original one after a change of variables. I used this idea in my answer below. It shows how to *find* the fundamental solution by a reasonable guess instead of just giving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parabolic operator with constant coefficients is a linear transformation away from the heat operator, so it is a natural guess that the fundamental solutions should be similar.
I will use this idea to find the fundamental solution.
(If you just want to see the solution, see the last line.)

Take two positive definite symmetric $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $Q$.
Consider the function $\phi_a(x)=\exp(-\frac1ax^TQx)$ with a parameter $a>0$.
A simple calculation gives
$$
\partial_i\partial_j\phi_a(x)
%=
%\partial_i[-\frac2a\phi_a(x)(Qx)_j]
%=
%\frac4{a^2}\phi_a(x)(Qx)_i(Qx)_j-\frac2a\phi_a(x)Q_{ij}
=
\frac2a\phi_a(x)(\frac2a(Qx)_i(Qx)_j-Q_{ij})
$$
and
$$
\partial_a\phi_a(x)=\frac1{a^2}\phi_a(x)x^TQx.
$$
Therefore the function $F(t,x)=t^{-n/2}\phi_{4t}(x)$ satisfies
$$
\partial_tF(t,x)
=
t^{-1}(-\frac n2+\frac1{4t}x^TQx)t^{-n/2}\phi_{4t}(x).
$$
Now consider the elliptic second order operator $L=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}\partial_i\partial_j$ — every elliptic second order operator with constant coefficients is of this form.
Now
$$
L\phi_a(x)
%=
%A_{ij}\frac2a\phi_a(x)(\frac2a(Qx)_i(Qx)_j-Q_{ij})
%=
%\frac2a\phi_a(x)(\frac2a A_{ij}(Qx)_i(Qx)_j-Q_{ij}A_{ij})
=
\frac2a\phi_a(x)(\frac2a x^TQAQx-\operatorname{tr}(QA)),
$$
so
$$
LF(t,x)
=
t^{-n/2}\frac1{2t}\phi_{4t}(x)(\frac1{2t} x^TQAQx-\operatorname{tr}(QA)).
$$
If we assume $Q=A^{-1}$, we get
$$
LF(t,x)
=
t^{-n/2}\frac1{t}\phi_{4t}(x)(\frac1{4t} x^TQx-n/2)
=
\partial_tF(t,x).
$$
We have thus found that $F$ with $Q=A^{-1}$ satisfies the heat equation for $t>0$, so it must be the fundamental solution — up to normalization.

To fix the normalization, we only need to evaluate a Gaussian integral at any fixed time.
Suppose the fundamental solution is $cF$ for a constant $c>0$.
We should have
$$
1
=
\int_{\mathbb R^n}cF(1,x)dx
%=
%c\int_{\mathbb R^n}\exp(-\frac14x^TA^{-1}x)dx
=
c\int_{\mathbb R^n}\exp(-\frac14|\sqrt Ax|^2)dx
%=
%c\int_{\mathbb R^n}\exp(-\frac14|y|^2)d(A^{-1/2}y)
=
c\det(A)^{-1/2}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\exp(-\frac14|y|^2)dy
=
c\det(A)^{-1/2}(4\pi)^{n/2}.
$$
Therefore the fundamental solution to the operator $L$ given by the matrix $A$ is
$$
F(t,x)
=
\det(A)^{1/2}(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\exp(-\frac1{4t}x^TA^{-1}x).
$$
Notice that when $A$ is the identity matrix, this is the usual formula as it should.

Comment: Thank you for your clear computations. I have only one question: why we're sure that is the fundamental solution? You say that since $F$ solves the equation for all $t>0$ then it must be the fund. sol. But why?

Comment: @foo90, that is a good question, because I didn't explain it properly. The Fundamental solution has two main properties: (1) it solves the heat equation for $t>0$ and (2) as $t\to0$, the function $F(t,\cdot)$ converges to the delta function in some sense. Why the second condition, then? It should not be too hard to check that for a bounded continuous function $f$ we have $f*F(t,\cdot)\to f$ pointwise as $t\to0$. This means that the fundamental solution gives solutions for any bounded continuous initial conditions in the usual way. (This is really what we want from a fundamental solution.)

Comment: Thank you another time. One last thing if you could answer, if the partial differential operator contains also the zero order term it's ok, I can write the FS starting from your formula. But if there are also first order terms how changes the formula?

Comment: @foo90, you are welcome. For a first order term you can try to use this observation: For two functions $f$ and $g$ you have $L(fg)=fLg+gLf+2\nabla f\cdot(A\nabla g)$. If $g(x)=\exp(y\cdot x)$ for a constant vector $y$, then $g^{-1}L(fg)=Lf+2(Ay)\cdot\nabla f+f(\text{tr}(A)+Ay\cdot y)$. Thus if $f$ solves an equation with first and second order terms, then $gf$ solves an equation without them. Choose the vector $y$ suitably. (I haven't checked, but this trick of multiplying with the exponential of a linear function often works with constant coefficients.)